# SQL Server data transfer from one server to another server

Tags: sql-server, replication

I want to transfer multiple tables and their data from one SQL Server to another SQL Server on the local network automatically every 1 hour.

Comment: If the 2 servers are SQL Servers, you should use Transnational Replication for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool built-in tool in SSMS to do this.

In SSMS, right click on the database name. Select Data > Import on the destination database. You will be prompted to provide connection information for the source database. This is internally using SSIS integration tool.

Comment: i don't want to do manually. it have to do automatically transfer data from one server to another server

Comment: You can save the SSIS package generated. Then you can run it via command line anytime. The command is dtexec.exe <filenameof ssis package>. You can also execute the ssis package from dot net code or powershell.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a `SSIS Package`  USE Type two `SCD` if you want insert and
   updates. you can use staging table from source to
   destination is a good practice and it is industry standard. if you
   are not having staging environment. You can use `temp tables` within
   `ssis package` to achieve the same.
2. Schedule a `job` and `run` that `ssis package` in the `job` for every half an hour

Comment: thank u . I am new to SSIS can give me any link how to use the ssis. I have to transfer around 1000 tables data for every hour.

Comment: You can read Microsoft docs [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-create-a-project-and-basic-package-with-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15) and [SSIS tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/ssis) tutorial.