# How could I generate SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

The situation is that I have two DB servers with SQL Server, I need to transfer the data from Server A to Server B automatically every night.

So according to [sql server data transfer from one server to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558624/sql-server-data-transfer-from-one-server-to-another-server), I created an SSIS project. And it manage to transfer data with good performance. But the question is, how do I export the project into SSIS package and run it every night?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/sql-server-agent-jobs-for-packages?view=sql-server-ver15#to-automate-package-execution-by-using-sql-server-agent) to shedule it. Are you having trouble with deploying ssis to [SSIS catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are still running it from Visual Studio. To schedule it daily you will need to do the below,

1. Deploy your project to a SQL Server
2. Create an Agent job and schedule it.

Found a good article, sharing that with you here.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9069/deploy-and-schedule-an-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-package-step-by-step/

Answer (score 1):

You can either store the package as in the file system or in the SSIS catalog. I would say that storing it in the SSIS catalog is the best way to go here.

Before you deploy your package to the SSIS catalog you need to make sure that integration services is installed on your server as well as that the SSIS catalog has been created.

[How to create ssis catalog](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2017/07/03/creating-the-ssis-catalog/)

If all above is OK then proceed and deploy your package and create an agent job. Please notice that you need to set up permissions for the sql agent account so it can access your databases.